# WSO2 bpmn-explorer - "Username or password invalid!"

Tags: wso2, wso2-business-process

We are running WSO2 IDS, ESB, BPS in Docker containers. All components are using  Identity Server and all works great, but when I'm trying to login to bpmn-explorer I'm getting "Username or password invalid!" I tried with default admin credentials, and also I have created new user directly in BPS but nothing works. Could you please tell me where can I find bpmn-explorer logs or what files I need to modify.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, and the solution is allowing more privileges to the admin account role on the carbon console of the BPS.

[Adding more permissions on BPS to the associated admin role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZSiR.jpg)

And the internal exception throwed with the problem was registered on the BPS carbon.log file:

```
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Invalid Permission root
 path provided
```

Now you can enter to the bpmn-explorer console.